# RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (30) : unknown error at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1501972792122/work/pytorch-0.1.12/torch/lib/THC/THCGeneral.c:66

Tags: ipython, spyder, pytorch

I'm getting a runtime error everytime I try to debug pytorch code for the second time. It seems like after restarting the ipython console some of the cuda programs are not canceled properly so that this error occurs while trying to rerun the code.
Has anyone had the same experience / knows how to solve it?
Is there a way to manually flush all cuda activities from my GPU?

I'm using pytorch version 0.1.12_1, ipython 4.2.0 and as IDE spyder 3.2.4.

Comment: That sounds weird, maybe you could try to post it in https://discuss.pytorch.org/

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just posted it there. Do you know a working combination of pytorch / ipython / spyder versions?

Comment: No idea, I have been using it in notebooks and did not experience that behaviour, sorry.